# Symfony2 Unable to dump assets in prod on Debian linux

Tags: php, linux, symfony, assets

On my localhost I was able to set up my app.php environment successfully. I was able to dump the assets `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`. However in a linux server I always get an error.

```
  Unable to load asset from URL "https://rawgit.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll/master/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"
```

I alrready tried to clear my cache with rm -rf * and all the permissions ar working.. I did everything exacly like I did in my local.. But I just can dump assets..

What is the problem? Why cant he load this asset..

**UPDATE**

So I created a js file and added the content in it. Placed it in resources/public/js folder.

I clear cache with `rm -rf *`

Then I did `assets:install`. This added my new file to web/bundles/mpshop/js/ folder.

Now when I try do dump assets I get:

```
The source file "/web/live/app/../web/bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js" does not exist.
```

But when i go to web/bundles/mpshop/js/ I can clearly see that the file is in there...

My base.html.twig:

```
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts
        'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery-ui.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/migrate.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/bootstrap-select.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/search.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/ckeditor.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/lightbox.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/slick/slick.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/custom.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/scroll-to-top.js'
        'bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js'
        %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: Can your server access this external URL? Maybe it'll be blocked by a firewall or some other kind of security. Try to download it with file_get_contents or something with an different script to try it out.

Comment: ping on your prod server the URL https://rawgit.com

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use external URL scripts.

Can you reach [rawgit.com](http://rawgit.com) from your production server ?
If not, stores the javascript on your server and changes the path of the script in your TWIG template.

Comment: Try once again to reset the symlink to your public folder : php app/console assets:install --symlink 

Then try to browser the URL : http://localhost/bundles/mpshop/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js, if not check your HTTP server configuration.